# Xml tokinizer with xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a xml string and i want to get specific node value with a method

```
String responseXML = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:getEmailUnsubscribeLinkResponse xmlns:ns2=\"http://bird.kartaca.com/xmlschema/admin/delivery\"><ns2:unsubscribeLink>http://google.com/552dcaac07d500743846b7ab967cfb90</ns2:unsubscribeLink></ns2:getEmailUnsubscribeLinkResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

String xmlPath2 = "/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns2:getEmailUnsubscribeLinkResponse";

String searchedText3 = "ns2:unsubscribeLink";
```

i want to get  "http://google.com/552dcaac07d500743846b7ab967cfb90" value from xml without substring but when i execute my method i am getting null pointer exception.My method is:

```
private String getReturnCodeForCCB(String responseXML, String expression, String searchedNode) {
        String response = "";
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(responseXML));
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        int length = nodeList.getLength();
        Node nNode = nodeList.item(0);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            NodeList nodes = eElement.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nodeCode = nodes.item(i);
                if(nodeCode.getNodeName().equals(searchedNode)){
                    response = nodeCode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this xpath : `//*[contains(namespace-uri(), 'http://bird.kartaca.com')][local-name()='unsubscribeLink']/text()`

You don't need to check `nodeCode.getName().equals(searchedNode)`

Your modified code would be :

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        int length = nodeList.getLength();
     if ( length > 0 )
     {
         Node nNode = nodeList.item(0);
         response = nNode.getNodeValue();
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but i updated my code with your comment nodelist returned null is there any problem in xpath usage?

Comment: I removed [contains(namespace-uri(),'http://bird.kartaca.com')] line from xpath and i get expected response my finally xpath string is "//*[local-name()='unsubscribeLink']/text()"